# PostgreSql Group into predefined groups, where one group acts as group anything thats left

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table with data similar to this.

```
create table DataTable {
name text,
value number
}

insert into DataTable values
('A', 1),('A', 2),('B', 3),('Other', 5),('C', 1);
```

I have 3 values A, B and Other.

I want to count the values so that the C get aggregated into Other

Expected output

```
Name  | sum
A     |  3
B     |  3
Other |  6
```

I know that the result could be achieved by 2 sub queries, 1 That groups only A, B and OTher and the other that count everything that isnt A or B or Other into Other. And then agggregate these 2 subqueries together.

My question is, is there a way to do this without multiple subqueries? Reson being, the actual query in the application is a monster with multiple joins and aggregations. Repeating the same piece of code multiple times would make it very hard to maintain. So im hoping there is a clever trick.

Comment: Might work :D. So simple that i didnt think about it. Il check it once im back behind work computer.

Comment: If you have a new/different requirement you should ask a new question and not change the current because this way you invalidate any answers that you have received.

Comment: @forpas wery well

Answer (score 1):

Simple CASE might do the job:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN name != 'A' AND name != 'B' THEN 'Other'
        ELSE name
    END AS mapped_name,
    SUM(value)
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY mapped_name
```

without any subquery at all.